# Terminal command after every boot

Tags: boot, command-line

How do I run this terminal command 10 seconds after log-in/boot:

```
imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"
```

I am using ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Not sure what Desktop Environment you are using or what version of Ubuntu you are using.  But the command would be `bash -c 'sleep 10 && imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"'` in your startup apps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

big thanks to  Terrance
figured it out.

1) created a new file /home/dexy/Stuff: "touch 'Mousewheel scrollwheel fix'"

2) pasted "  bash -c 'sleep 2 && imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"'  "

3) saved

4) went to "Startup Application Preferences"

5) add

6) name: Mouse Scroll

7) command: "/home/dexy/Stuff/Mouse scrollwheel fix"

8) save